# Bootstrap popup modal appears to small and in wrong position

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, popup, bootstrap-modal

[SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVNKj.png)I need a modal on my website and i decided to  litterally copy the code for a modal on the bootstrap website. Only now it displays very small.

This is the modal code:

```html
<!-- Modal (EXACT COPY FROM BOOTSTRAP) -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add an working example snippet. And maybe an image of the modal you see, because we don't know what _Only now it displays very small_ means.

Comment: Have you used the CSS and JS with this HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a **Bootstrap v4** modal for your site they're quite self explanatory. But for example sake and to hopefully help you. The code below will work for a **Bootstrap** modal pop-up (large):

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Large Modal</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this made it better, but still the X(for closing) will show somwhere in the top center instead of top right.

Comment: It shouldn't do if you've used the code I provided?